# Monodb query nested object by two fields

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, mongodb-query

I need to get a document from "documents" by clientId and documentId. How can I retrieve the data?
Schema:

```
{
    _id: ObjectId('64cd1e1877dd3b45ce2715d4'),
    name: 'string',
    clientId: '79fc89fe-32de-11ee-be56-0242ac120002',
    dateBirth: ISODate('2023-08-04T10:49:30.594Z'),
    addressReg: 'string',
    addressFact: 'string',
    passportSeries: 'string',
    passportNumber: 'string',
    mobilePhone: 'string',
    anotherMobilePhone: 'string',
    email: 'string',
    oneMoreEmail: 'string',
    cardName: 'string',
    currencyName: 'string',
    paymentSystem: 'string',
    tariff: 'string',
    signingDate: ISODate('2023-08-04T10:49:30.594Z'),
    documents: [
        {
            clientId: '79fc89fe-32de-11ee-be56-0242ac120002',
            documentId: '64cd160a68f6d71fc5f68098',
            title: 'T_rules.md',
            signed: true
        }
    ],
    _class: 'com.example.mvpmongo.model.ClientData'
}
```

When I try this query I get null, though clientId and documentId are correct.

```
   @Query("{ $and: [{'documents' : { $elemMatch: {'documentId': ?1}}},{'clientId': ?0}]}")
    SignedDocument findDocument(String clientId, String documentId);
```

I'm new to mongo, could you please explain to me what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Your nesting in the query isn't correct. You need to move two of the three closing braces that are currently between `documentId` and `clientId` to instead be at the end of the object/argument

Comment: @user20042973 I'm sorry, English is not my first language, could you please clarify?

Comment: I tried it like this:@Query("{'documents': {$elemMatch:{'documentId': ?1,'clientId':?0}}}"), but I got this: SignedDocument(clientId=79fc89fe-32de-11ee-be56-0242ac120002, documentId=null, title=null, signed=false). It makes no sense, all fields should contain data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple solutions to your problem. I created a [GitHub repo](https://github.com/Lefeverw/stackoverflow-mongodb-query-example) showing the different options:

1. **Creating a custom query**

In your case the query would look as follows:

```
@Query(value = "{ $and: [{'documents.clientId' :  ?0},{'documents.documentId' :  ?1}]}", fields = "{ 'documents' : 1}")
ClientData findDocument(String clientId, String documentId);
```

Note that this query returns `ClientData` (including the entire list of `SignedDocument`), so you still need to filter the result afterwards.

*the fields parameter is not mandatory, but in case there are many attributes you can use it to indicate which attributes you want to retrieve. The others are null.

2. **Creating a custom method**

```
ClientData findByDocuments_ClientIdAndDocuments_DocumentId(String clientId, String documentId);
```

In this case Spring derives the query from the method name directly.
Note that you still need to do the filtering, since you retrieve the `ClientData` object.

3. **Use unwinding**

This one is a bit more complex. Basically, you need to create a separate class `SignedDocumentUnwinded` and convert the result of your query to this class.

```
UnwindOperation unwind = Aggregation.unwind("documents");
MatchOperation match = Aggregation.match(Criteria.where("documents.clientId").is(requestedClientId).and("documents.documentId").is(requestedDocumentId));
Aggregation aggregation = Aggregation.newAggregation(unwind, match);
AggregationResults<SignedDocumentUnwind> results = mongoTemplate.aggregate(aggregation, "client_data",
                SignedDocumentUnwind.class);
return results.getMappedResults().stream().map(SignedDocumentUnwind::getDocuments).toList();
```

The advantage is that there's no need to filter for the requested `SignedDocument`.